# ASPX Hyperlink appearing as plain text in email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I just want to send a email with an hyperlink but it kept appearing as plain text:

Button Click:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            currURL = Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

            string emailSubject = "Hello World";
            string emailBody = "Please click <a href='" + currURL "'>HERE</a>" Debug: " + currURL;

            myClass.SendEmail(tb_EmailTo.Text, emailSubject, emailBody);
    }
```

Code that Sends the email:

```
    public static void SendEmail(string sendTo, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHTML = true)
    {
        SmtpClient Smtp_Server = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage e_mail = new MailMessage();
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(---, ---);
        Smtp_Server.Port = thePort;
        //Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = theHost;

        e_mail = new MailMessage();
        e_mail.From = new MailAddress(theSendFromAddress);

        e_mail.To.Add(sendTo);

        string currPathAndQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        string currURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(currPathAndQuery, "/");

        e_mail.Subject = subject;
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        e_mail.Body = body;
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail);
    }
```

The Email is sent with the body being:

> Please click HERE Debug: localhost:12345/

There HERE is supposed to be a hyper link pointing to the localhost:12345/ but it kept appearing as just a plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, turns out the link: currURL is giving problems, added http:// to it and it worked